# Magento 2 cart rule not working

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules

I have created a cart rule in my magento 2 site. It's working on my local environment. but it's not working in live( production) site.

All the target items not able to add to cart after rule activated. 
otherwise fine.

I have checked all the configurations in my local site. but not found any issue with live.

Is this a known bug or what can be the issue that I am facing?.

Please help.

Comment: maybe cache. I think so?

Comment: Hi Himani, 
No. I have created a simple rule and tried.  if there is any active rule targeted items of that rule cant add to cart.

Comment: You have checked console or var/log?

Comment: Have you check magento log file and console?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya I have found "Array to string conversion" issue in log files

Comment: @MichaelHa "Array to string conversion"  issue found in log files

Comment: then try to solve that error first and then check.

Comment: guys, I have fied that issue.  there was a plugin that changed the vendor modules. so now i have removed that and its fixed now.